# How do I get HTML text from a web page without having it rendered?

Tags: php, html

Using cURL or this ...

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
```

gets the web page, but it also renders it as a normal web page and I just want the text.

Comment: What do you mean "rendered"? No, it's not "rendered".

Comment: When you say you just want the text, how do you mean - of a particular element? Or all text, with the tags removed?

Comment: Minitech it is rendered.  I run a php script using ajax and then echo what should be html source code back into my regular page from the script.  Instead of getting html or xml style source code it gives me the pictures, css formatting, everything. I just want the view-source code

Comment: Also I did something really stupid... I outputted the buffer using foo.HTML(data I recieved back) which obviously turned everything to html when I should have been using foo.TEXT(data I receieved)... Hours wasted!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm... all `file_get_contents` does is get the contents of the file. It only looks like "rendered" HTML because you're dumping it right into the output stream. Try running it through `htmlspecialchars` before outputting it.

Comment: Look at the comment I gave to minitech... How do I just get the xml style tags you see when you right click and view source??

Comment: Because it's encoding the `<` into `&lt;` so that the browser doesn't recognise it as HTML anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I'll *assume* you're just doing `echo $html` and assuming it's rendered somehow. It's not. Look at it in plain text instead:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo $html;
```

And if by "rendered" you mean "ASP.NET rendered the page into HTML", no, you can't get the source of arbitrary remote pages. That would be a pretty big security risk.

Comment: This is the code Im running ....                                          

<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
// $url = strip_tags($_POST['url']);
//$html = file_get_contents($url);
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'; 


$html = file_get_contents('http://yahoo.com');

echo $html;

?>                

It gives me the yahoo page as you would see it if you went to www.yahoo.com

Comment: @Leon: Mmm... doesn't for me. Are you getting any warnings? Is there any content *before* your opening `<?php` tag? Headers have to come before any content, and that includes whitespace.

Comment: @Leon: Ah, it's *using Ajax*. See, details like that are important. You can keep the PHP exactly as it is, but you need to do the actual "escaping" in JavaScript. Please post your Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks minitech but i just had to use htmlspecialchars

Comment: @Leon: That's the bad way to do it, which is why I asked. You should do the escaping client-side, or you have to transfer about 2.5x as much data with less extensibility.

Comment: @Leon: I realize you're not sure how, and that's why I'm asking you to post your code. As for why - read the second sentence of my last comment again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Kolink.  Something like this will work:

```
$html = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'));
```

Not tested, though pretty confidant!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "just the text"?  Do you want to scrape the text *content* of the html file? Then you should try to parse the file, i.e. filtering the tags that contain interesting content with a tool like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (look for the tab "extract content from html").  Or write your own parser and, if necessary, strip the remaining tags from the content with php's own [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php).